# Choropleth in Cartodb with lat and long of countries

Tags: carto, choropleth

I have a dataset in Cartodb with the following columns:

`Name,Count,Lat,Long`

When I upload the dataset, Cartodb automatically update the column Geometry with the Lat and Long.

The Lat and Long in my datasets are the centre of countries. So, I have only once combination of Lat and Long per country.

I want to use the Count and create a Choropleth for the countries that have the Lat and Long in my dataset.

I did it in the past with another dataset, but unfortunately, I haven't kept the procedure to do it again.

Comment: So it sounds like you need to join the LAT/LON points to the associated Country polygons - perhaps you could also upload the Natural Earth Countries dataset, and use the SQL spatial interface to intersect the points and polygons, giving the values from the points to the polygons, and use that data to drive the choropleth... or... pre-process it all in QGIS using those tools, and upload the polygons to CartoDB...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `merge dataset` option in order to join your data with a countries dataset.

1. In data library, upload "World borders", which is basically a dataset of all countries in the world.
2. Inside the world_borders dataset, in the "Table view", select "merge dataset" option in the right toolbar.
3. Choose "spatial join".
4. In the column selector for the world_borders table, select the_geom (it is by default) and for example "name" or any other information you want to have in your new table about the countries.
5. In the second dataset selector, choose the table that you are specifying in this question. Choose your `count` column, select the `SUM` operation and click on merge. This will sum the "count" inside the countries and will give you as a result a dataset with the country shapes and your aggregated count column for each of them.
6. Now, you're able to perform a choropleth dataset on this new dataset.

[image: merge example]

If in your dataset you had also the names of the countries, you could have geocoder the dataset by this name. Assuming that you have a single row per country, the result would have been equivalent and more straightforward.